# Binding command of itemsource object xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a page with Listview, whose Itemsource is observable collection of Class A. Now inside the listview cell I need to assign the command of Class A object. But the command is not getting triggered. below is my code.

**Main Page**

```
<ListView  x:Name="lstInventoryRequests" 
           HasUnevenRows="True"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding LstInventoryRequests}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
                 <ViewCell.View>
                     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                  VerticalOptions="Fill">
                         <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                         <Button Text="Acknowledge" 
                                 Command="{Binding AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                     </StackLayout>
                 </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Page View Model**

```
LstInventoryRequests = new Observablecollection(){new A(){ItemName= "someitem"}}
```

**ItemSource Class**

```
  class A
   {
       public Command<InventoryRequestsDetails> AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive;
        public A()
         {

            AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive = new Command<InventoryRequestsDetails>(async (arg) => await Handler(arg));
         }

        private async Task Handler(InventoryRequestsDetails arg)
          {
           //MyLogic
          }
   }
```

Now Button command is not hitting "Handler" method. Can anyone help me to identify; where is my code goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the BindingContext

```
<Button Text="Acknowledge" Command="{Binding AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive}" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference lstInventoryRequests}, Path=BindingContext}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but still its not hitting the command handler. :(

Comment: https://techsolutions2017.blogspot.it/2017/01/listview-in-xamarin-forms-in-mvvm.html#comment-form try this link

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your list to an observable collection of items of type A. Each A has a command which is strongly typed and expects an item of type InventoryRequestsDetails.

In your binding, however, you are binding to ., i.e. the bound item, which is of type A. I can't tell anything about the type InventoryRequestsDetails from your code, but if you update your command to accept an item of type A then your command should be hit:

```
   class A
   {
       public Command<A> AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive;
        public A()
         {

            AcknowledgeInventoryItemsReceive = new Command<A>(async (arg) => await Handler(arg));
         }

        private async Task Handler(A arg)
          {
           // You should get an A object as the value of arg here :)
          }
   }
```

Alternatively, your binding should reference a InventoryRequestsDetails object rather than . for an A.